# Cannot install / run service - missing assembly.

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, ssis

I have been unable to install a windows service; I get the following error when attempting to install via ClickOnce.

I have version 12.0.0.0 on the machine/and can only find version 12.0.0.0 - does anyone know a source for version 13.0.0.0. The server is running SQL 2016 Developer, as is my development environment.

I am not even sure where the reference to version 13.0.0.0 is coming from! It ends up in the exe.manifest, but for the life of me, I cannot find where this has come from?

[image: Missing assembly]

Comment: Sql server 2016 is version 13.0.x.x.  Besides that, what are you trying to install exactly and what are you clicking on to do it?